How to share ember app's styles to ember-engine addon
may I ask for help please?
Given statement: I've imported the app's styles in my addon's stylesheet by referencing the path relative to the project root.
Problem statement: When I am running my ember-engine (addon), I am getting this error Can't find stylesheet to import. Tho the stylesheet file is present.
This is my following structure
/app
/ember-engine-addon
  /addon
    /styles
      addon.scss

In my addon.scss, I've imported the app's styles:
// my-addon/addon/styles/addon.scss
@import '/app/styles/app';

